# How to insert timeseries data in to Prometheus

Tags: time-series, prometheus

I've a bunch of APIs which can fetch timeseries data on various matrix e.g. CPU, memory etc etc. I need to insert this in Prometheus. How do I do this? I don't want to use an intermediate DB e.g. MySQL etc. Also, I am unable to find detailed info on Prometheus e.g. data structures, tables, data input\output etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Either by scraping or using a prometheus push gateway: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to push the data to Prometheus-compatible monitoring systems such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). It supports various popular data ingestion protocols such as InfluxDB, Graphite, OpenTSDB, DataDog, CSV, etc. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-import-time-series-data) for details.